# How to redirect django url in off business hours

Tags: python, django

There is a requirement like app should be available in business hours 9 AM -6 PM and rest time, it should redirect to just one well defined page. Can someone explain me how to achieve this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

do a middleware and add the conditional for redirect

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from datetime import datetime

def simple_middleware(get_response):
    # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def middleware(request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = get_response(request)
        # if the actual hour is not between start and end redirect.
        if not start <= datetime.now() <= end:
            return redirect("/")
        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response

    return middleware
```